# bash: iwconfig: command not found | [debian]

Tags: networking, debian

**Question**: How to use `iwconfig` in *fresh* Debian install?

**Log**

```
root@debian:/home/[usr]# apt install --reinstall wireless-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 114 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 wireless-tools amd64 30~pre9-13 [114 kB]
Fetched 114 kB in 0s (595 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 176551 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wireless-tools_30~pre9-13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wireless-tools (30~pre9-13) over (30~pre9-13) ...
Setting up wireless-tools (30~pre9-13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
root@debian:/home/[usr]# iwconfig
bash: iwconfig: command not found
root@debian:/home/[usr]#
```

Comment: Maybe you can use [`iw`](https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/iw).

Answer (score 0):

What command did you use to get root? You may not have /sbin in your path.

Try `/sbin/iwconfig`